# GCC: Specifying mmx register for a local variable fails

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, g++, mingw

Im trying to achieve the following on a Windows environment c++, MINGW GCC:

Im trying to define a local variable as such:

`register DWORD index __asm  ("%mm7");`

this definition compiles with MINGW GCC x64 , but fails on x86 compilation with the error 
`error: invalid register name for 'index'
     register DWORD index __asm  ("%mm7");`

I have already tried to reference the register as `__asm  ("mm7");` but to no avail. any help on the matter would be very appreciated

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can only use general purpose registers with this feature.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Whats weird is that it does succeed on a x64 toolchain compilation. im trying to save the value in this register to be referenced later by a different func, by accessing the register

Comment: That is not a valid use case of register variables.  Remember, `xmm` registers are caller saved, so before your other code is reached, it might already be overwritten by some other function.

Comment: I know that but im willing to take the risk, those functions are sequential

Comment: Try specifying `-march=native` or `-mmmx`.

Comment: @fuz, they are using MMX - not XMM.

Comment: I'd also question how this is being used.It should be noted that using `register DWORD index __asm ("%mm7");` doesn't guarantee the variable `index` would be in _mm7_. The only guarantee is that if `index` was used as an operand to inline assembly using a `"y"` constraint, _mm7_ would be the register used. As @MaximEgorushkin points out to even get this going you'd have to tell the compiler to use MMX via the `-mmmx` option. x86-64 should compile without error b/c all x86-64 processors can use MMX registers,but not all x86 targets support MMX so the compiler has to be told to use them or not.

Comment: Compiling without error and generating the code you expect are two different issues.

Comment: @fuz: I thought you could use call-clobbered registers; the compiler saves/restores them for you by copying somewhere else across function calls.  But it seems you're right; gcc doesn't save/restore mm7 across a call to `bar()` in its code-gen here: https://godbolt.org/z/kt-brt.  It only spills mm7 *after*, to get it into integer regs in 32-bit mode.  And yes, Maxim is correct: `-m32` baseline doesn't include `-mmmx`, so mm7 isn't a valid register name.  But x86-64 does.